# Import class into another folder in the same package python

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror

I am trying to create a package for my own use and cannot seem to be able to import a class into another folder. Here is a image of my current directory.

[image]

I am trying to import a class from `strategies.core` into my `test/test_symbol.py` file but it keeps giving me an ModuleNotFoundError

### Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\Francois\Desktop\H4Impulse\test\test_symbol.py", line 6, in <module>
from strategies.core import Symbol
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'strategies'
```

### test_symbol.py

```
import unittest
# import sys
# sys.path.append(r"C:\Users\Francois\Desktop\H4Impulse")


from strategies.core import Symbol
# from ..strategies.core import Symbol <--- this also doesn't work
class TestSymbol(unittest.TestCase):
    pass



unittest.main()
```

it works when I use `sys.path.append` to append the path but I feel like this shouldn't be necessary. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since you are running "\test\test_symbol.py", I assume your working directory might be "\test", thus it is not finding the `strategies` module within that folder. Can you confirm your working directory?

Comment: Did you tried from .strategies.core import Symbol (with a single dot) to go one level up he directory

Comment: How are you invoking `test_symbol.py`?  You should do it from the project level directory. You should probably also use [test discovery](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#test-discovery) rather than call the test script directly.

Comment: Did you tried from .strategies.core import Symbol (with a single dot) to go one level up he directory

Comment: I did not execute the file from the project level directory. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

Problem lies in your path. You are using:

- absolute path in `sys.path.append`
- relative path in your import

Probably if you call `sys.path.append(r"./")` it would raise the same `ModuleNotFoundError` error.

Since you are running the script "c:\Users\Francois\Desktop\H4Impulse\test\test_symbol.py", your working directory is probably set as "c:\Users\Francois\Desktop\H4Impulse\test". In this folder, the module `strategies` does not exist.

Finally, you should either:

- Set "c:\Users\Francois\Desktop\H4Impulse" as your working directory (suggested if it is THE directory of your project)
- Use [relative imports](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14132912/13541354)